# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState exception in specific android devices

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application is running successfully in most of the devices. However, today its getting crashed in some of the devices. Upon inquiry, i got the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
                                                                             at com.xyz.fieldquote.Activities.RegistrationActivity$2.onErrorResponse(RegistrationActivity.java:190)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:598)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Below I am posting my code , where I am getting the error. Here if I am getting a 200 response, I am calling an activity, else in case of error response, I am calling a fragment.

```
public void tryLogIn( String str_uuid) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        volleyQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(apiClass.QUOTE_LOG_IN + str_uuid, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("recommendationresponse",response+"");
                        String str_fsrID = "", str_userName = "", str_fsrName;
                        int int_notificationNumber;
                        boolean bool_whitelisted;
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            int int_response_code = response.getInt("OK");

                            Log.d("response",int_response_code+"");

                            if(int_response_code==200)
                            {
                                bool_whitelisted = data.getBoolean("IsWhitelisted");
                                Log.d("response",bool_whitelisted+"");

                                if(bool_whitelisted == true)
                                {
                                    str_fsrID = data.getString("VendorId");
                                    str_userName = data.getString("UserName");
                                    str_fsrName = data.getString("FsrName");

                                    JSONArray notificationArray = data.optJSONArray("MessageNotification");

                                    if(notificationArray==null)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("arrayresponse","null");
                                        int_notificationNumber = -1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Log.d("arrayresponse",notificationArray.length()+"");
                                        int_notificationNumber = notificationArray.length();
                                        for(int i = 0;i< notificationArray.length();i++)
                                        {
                                            alst_notificationList.add((String) notificationArray.get(i));
                                        }
                                    }


                                    Log.d("login", response + "" + str_fsrID);

                                     shrp_sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("pdfPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shrp_sharedpreferences.edit();

                                    editor.putString("fsrID", str_fsrID);
                                    editor.putString("username", str_userName);
                                    editor.putString("fsrname", str_fsrName);
                                    editor.putInt("notificationNumber", int_notificationNumber);
                                    editor.commit();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    RegistrationActivity.this.finish();

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!isFinishing()) {
                                    blankFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.registrationContainer, blankFragment).commit();
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (!isFinishing()) {
                    blankFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.registrationContainer, blankFragment).commit();
                }


            }
```

The OnCreate() of the activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    alst_notificationList = new ArrayList<String>();
    shrp_sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(pdfPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(isTablet(this))
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    apiClass = new webAPIs();
    str_uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.d("uuid",str_uuid);

    tryLogIn(str_uuid);


}
```

The error is coming inside the onErrorResponse()  fragmenttransaction line.

I even made some changes like calling commitAllowingStateLoss(), which gave me an Activity is Destroyed exception. I am actually very much clueless regarding the whole scenario. Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question and put back this `commitAllowingStateLoss()` in your code? Is it placed inside the `if (!isFinishing())` statement?

Comment: @pleft : yes in place of commit() inside the if (!isFinishing()) statement, I had added commitAllowingStateLoss()

Comment: Can you also share your main `activity` code (the one that has the `tryLogIn` method)?

Comment: @pleft: Hi, updated the question. Please have a look inside the OnCreate()

Comment: Last thing, change your `if (!isFinishing())` to `if (!isFinishing() || !isDestroyed())` and check again (only if you build your app for API level 17 and above (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29)

Comment: @pleft: Thank you. It kind of worked on the emulators. Let me try this on devices.